# depmod stuck after I install synaptics and run 'sudo apt update',

Tags: linux, ubuntu

output:
jane@Shiguang:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for jane:
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
jane@Shiguang:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up evdi (1.14.2-69) ...
Removing old evdi/1.14.2 module.
Module evdi-1.14.2 for kernel 6.2.0-39-generic (x86_64).
Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

evdi.ko:

- Uninstallation

  - Deleting from: /lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/
- Original module

  - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
  - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
    depmod...
    Deleting module evdi-1.14.2 completely from the DKMS tree.
    Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
    Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
    Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
    Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.2/source -> /usr/src/evdi-1.14.2

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-39-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.2.0-39-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...
Signing module /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.14.2/build/evdi.ko
Cleaning build area...

evdi.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

- Original module

  - No original module exists within this kernel
- Installation

  - Installing to /lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/
    depmod...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.